# Why does SSH hosts keys differ when connecting if the host_keys are the same?

Tags: sshd

There are 3 machines: A (from where I connect to B and C), B, and C. 
B and C have the same SSHD host keys (they have been copied, so they are 100% the same, SSHD has been restarted too, identical sshd_config file).

On C the known_hosts file looks like this:

```
C:~/.ssh # grep B *
C:~/.ssh # grep A *
known_hosts:ssh-rsa xxxx...xxxx
C:~/.ssh #
```

When we try to connect from C to A then "A" offers it's RSA hosts key.  
When we try to connect from C to B then "B" offers it's ECDSA hosts key.

**Question:** Why? Wouldn't it be logical that the "A" and "B" server should offer both the ex.: their RSA SSHD hosts keys?

Comment: Is the `sshd_config` on B the same as A?  That determines what B and A ask C for.

Comment: @goldilocks according to the question the configs are the same as well.

Comment: @peterph : No, according to the question as written B and C are the same.

Comment: Right. In that case however, the question seems rather strange: B and C have identical configuration/keys, but question is about connectoing **from** C to A and B. Please clarify.

Comment: what does sshd_config settings have to do with the whole thing _on server A_? I think nothing.

Comment: @gaskopeter you mention B and C have the same config, but connecting **from C to A and B**. You need to state something about configurations of the servers you are comparing, i.e. **A and B**, not **B and C**. Hence one part of the question is misleading at best.

Comment: @gaskopeter : If you are talking about C connecting to A, then A's `sshd_config` has *everything* to do with it.  What has nothing to do with it is C's sshd_config, since **C is the client**.  `sshd` is the *server*.  `ssh` is the *client*.  **They are not the same program** and they do not use the same config file.  Moreover, it is the server's settings (in this case, A) that determine what kind of keys it will use with the client.  Thus, to repeat, if the issue has to do with C connecting to A, A's `sshd_config` is what you should be considering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ECDH/ECDSA keys are preferred when learning a host key for the first time.  Since host C already knows host A's RSA key, it keeps using that.  But since host C knows nothing about host B's keys, the ECDH/ECDSA is used.

(I referenced the [release notes for 5.7](http://www.openssh.org/txt/release-5.7), when ECDH/ECDSA was introduced).

Questions I got:
*Are both keys needed?*  Well, yes.  Not every install of SSH out there supports ECDSA, so you need RSA.  (For example, putty doesn't do ECDSA yet)
*What happens if I only had ECDSA?*  Depends on who is trying to contact you.  If they support ECDSA, then everything works as expected.  If they don't, you'll get a failure of some sort.
*Which one is better?*  I personally don't know.  ECDSA requires less horsepower, so I have found it more snappy on older hardware.  And since OpenSSH prefers it over RSA, I'm guessing the developers think ECDSA is better.

Comment: Can you link from original source please? are both keys needed? what happens if only I would leave ECDSA? which one is better? RSA or the mentioned?

Comment: I added answers to these questions to my answer via edit.

Comment: @gaskopeter Out of curiosity (and also since I gave you basically the same answer earlier): what was the reason in the end for the servers offering different certificates?

Comment: As for ECC - there is currently some uncertainty as to how secure the exact curve used really is, due to NSA being the one behind the constants used for the NIST curve.

Comment: @peterph The difference was I explained why it happened even in a case where both were the same version.  He just happened to have RSA already in his known_hosts for host A.  So since it already knows A by an RSA host key, that key was presented.  Host B wasn't in known_hosts, so the preference for ECDSA took priority.

Comment: @kurtm oh, ok. Right you are.

Answer (score 0):

Do the servers you are trying to connect to have the same `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and/or OpenSSH (and OpenSSL) versions (the bits about identical configs and where are you connecting to seem to be a bit contradictory)? ECDH/ECDSA was introduced in OpenSSH 5.7p1 so if one server is older, it will just ignore the key file.

Comment: they are both version 5.8. yes, both B and C have the same sshd_config. (hostkeyfile line hashmarked)

Comment: openssl versions are the same too